# How did slavery become a legal institution in the United States?

Tags: united-states, law, legislative-process, slavery

The second paragraph in the Unites States Declaration of Independence states:

> “We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all Men are created equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty, and the Pursuit of Happiness.”

Since this is the case, how was slavery legal?
What I mean by this is how did lawyers and law makers convince the legislative branch to legalize owning / selling other people?

**NOTE**: Follow site rules and don't use this post as a platform to offend others, thanks.

Comment: I'll post a fuller answer when I get time, but I believe it all stemmed from (1)the 3/5ths compromise and (2) the lack of plaintiffs bringing cases

Comment: Do you mean in pre-Constitution America, or afterwards? Because the roots of slavery extend to its push on the Colonies.

Comment: Wrong question, slavery was legal **before** the Declaration of Independence. It was mostly "justified" in racist theories (black people got "civilization" and Christianism in exchange of their work, they were unable to take care of themselves, etc.) and economics (those who profited from slavery were usually rich people) did the rest. Anyway, I think it is better suited for History.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about history not political processes or policies

Comment: @DavidGrinberg the 3/5th compromise had nothing to do with the legal basis of slavery, which was an institution that extents to prehistory.  We're looking at this all retroactively.  For the time, the quoted sentence does not contradict indenturement whatsoever.

Comment: @hownowbrowncow It does have to do with the legal basis of slavery _in the United States_. This question is not asking why slavery was legal dating back to prehistory. Its specifically asking what were the legal justifications _in the US_. The basic argument was (and Ill find citation later on) if you are 3/5ths of a man, you are not a man, and therefore you are not counted as the men referenced in that passage

Comment: Slavery was already legal in the system that predated the founding of the US, and the laws in existence at the time were just continued.  Those laws that the people wanted to change were changed.  So if you want to know why slavery was legal in the US, you will not find the answer in the US constitution; you have to look at the legality of slavery in Europe, and, in particular, in the overseas possessions England (later Great Britain).

Comment: @DavidGrinberg The 3/5 compromise had nothing to do with the status of the slaves. It only had to do with the apportionment of seats in the House of Representatives. The North (free states) wanted slaves to not count because they were not considered citizens in the slave states and the South (slave holding states) wanted them to count fully (to increase thir political power).

Comment: @sabbahillel I know what the original purpose of 3/5ths was. My point is that it _also_ was used as ammunition for legal arguments defending slavery. You're mixing up what Im saying

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Where was it used as justification?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be noted that slavery as an institution existed throughout the world long before the American Revolution. As a result, those states whose laws did not ban slavery had the legality "grandfathered" in.

While there were those who wanted to ban slavery, the slave holding states refused to accept the constitution unless it were left legal.

[The Constitution and Slavery](http://www.crf-usa.org/black-history-month/the-constitution-and-slavery)

> Many colonists, even slave holders, hated slavery. Jefferson called it
>   a “hideous blot” on America. George Washington, who owned hundreds of
>   slaves, denounced it as “repugnant.” James Mason, a Virginia slave
>   owner, condemned it as “evil.”
>
> But even though many of them decried it, Southern colonists relied on
>   slavery. The Southern colonies were among the richest in America.
>   Their cash crops of tobacco, indigo, and rice depended on slave labor.
>   They weren’t going to give it up.

The Northern states wanted slaves to not count in the determination of how many Representatives a state could have in Congress and to ban the import of new slaves from outside the country. They expected that the slave trade would die off by itself (since they did not anticipate the invention of the cotton gin).

> Only the Southern states had large numbers of slaves. Counting them as
>   part of the population would greatly increase the South’s political
>   power, but it would also mean paying higher taxes. This was a price
>   the Southern states were willing to pay. They argued in favor of
>   counting slaves. Northern states disagreed. The delegates compromised.
>   Each slave would count as three-fifths of a person.
>
> Following this compromise, another controversy erupted: What should be
>   done about the slave trade, the importing of new slaves into the
>   United States? Ten states had already outlawed it. Many delegates
>   heatedly denounced it. But the three states that allowed it — Georgia
>   and the two Carolinas — threatened to leave the convention if the
>   trade were banned. A special committee worked out another compromise:
>   Congress would have the power to ban the slave trade, but not until
>   1800. The convention voted to extend the date to 1808.

This caused the inclusion of [Article I Section 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_One_of_the_United_States_Constitution#Section_9:_Limits_on_Congress)

> The first clause in this section prevents Congress from passing any
>   law that would restrict the importation of slaves into the United
>   States prior to 1808. Congress could however, levy a per capita duty
>   of up to ten dollars for each slave imported into the country. This
>   clause was further entrenched into the Constitution by Article V,
>   where it is explicitly shielded from constitutional amendment prior to
>   1808. On March 2, 1807, Congress approved legislation prohibiting the importation of slaves into the United States, which went into effect
>   January 1, 1808, the first day permitted by the Constitution.

Comment: This answer is totally right that slavery has been the norm throughout a lot of history; however, it is a bit misleading about the position of the founders on the issue of slavery.  First of all, slavery was widespread throughout the country. Although most slaves were in the South, there were plenty of slaves in the North, and they remained legal into the 19th century. Second, Jefferson did not hate slavery. He may have had some bad words for it, but he was a vicious slave owner who exploited his slaves mercilessly and campaigned against manumission, for example.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that the founders did not think that black Americans were people in the same way they were people, or, more directly, that they were fully human.  Here is Jefferson about slaves, summing up mainstream views of "science" at his time: https://web.archive.org/web/20110221131356/http://etext.lib.virginia.edu/etcbin/toccer-new2?id=JefVirg.sgm&images=images/modeng&data=/texts/english/modeng/parsed&tag=public&part=14&division=div1.